# Identify/substitute an SMD MOSFET labeled "540N 88KFG" for LCD monitor repair

Tags: mosfet, identification, substitution

I'm trying to repair the logic board of an LCD monitor that died while giving off a burned smell.

It seems that an LCD driver chip and a MOSFET (I think) burned out. The chip was easy to identify ([HV9982](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=HV9982)) and order, but I can't unambiguously identify and find a replacement for the other part.

It is labeled "540N 88KFG" and I think its form factor is TO-252 / DPAK. Below is a photo, there are three of them in the middle of the picture.

A related question is what characteristics I have to make sure to match if I can't buy an exact replacement. Searching around for "540N" MOSFET, I found some in other packages whose main data points were

- 100V source-drain voltage
- 33A current rating.

If those do indeed apply to this component as well, what else needs to match in a replacement?

**Update:** After looking around a bit longer it appears that [IRFR3410PbF](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/200/irfr3410pbf-84807.pdf) might be a reasonable replacement.

[image: 540N 88KFG MOSFET]

Comment: looks like some smps there, I would say gate capacitance and rdson would play a role too

Comment: Smells like a IRF540, but "N" usually means some sort of TO-220.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A REPAIR QUESTION, IT IS PART IDENTIFICATION FFS

Comment: @Passerby, the very first words of the title I chose are "Identify/substitute", and the tags I applied are "identification" and "substitution". Can you elaborate on what else you'd like to see?

Comment: @MarcLiyanage: He's complaining about the person that voted to close this as a repair question. Which it is not.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Chinese often put part numbers that are familiar into different packages than the original- eg. 1N5819 in MELF rather than DO-41, MJE13003 in TO-92 rather than TO-225 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a [Ceu540n](http://web2.cet-mos.com/PDF/CET-MOS/TO-251-252-N/U540N.PDF), or similar 'clone' of the IRF540.